# How to use Drawing Manager in Google Maps to draw curves and bezier

Tags: google-maps, google-api

Look at the following example:
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=toolbar_draw

In this example using the Esri drawing tools I can draw curves and beziers over the map, ho can I do the same using Google Map?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already familiar with all of that. I need to know how to create spline, beziers and all different types of curved segments. I don't need to create marks and then connect them. I need a direct method to do the drawing of curvature.